# Unable to format Micro SD card from ubuntu, android

Tags: 14.04

I have a Samsung MicroSD card of 8GB class 6 that was in my cellphone for around a year. Now I am unable to format it so as to clear all the data stored in it. I have used

```
sudo hdparm -r0 /dev/sdb
sudo mkfs -t vfat /dev/sdb1
```

And still the data remains in the drive. Its has become read-only since I cannot backup anything in the either from Ubuntu or from Android.

Comment: What errors are given by the commands?

Comment: `sudo hdparm -r0 /dev/sdb`
`/dev/sdb:`
`setting readonly to 0 (off)`
`readonly      =  0 (off)`
|
`sudo mkfs -t vfat /dev/sdb1`
`mkfs.fat 3.0.26 (2014-03-07)`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My sd-card would only mount read-only. For many Sd-card adapters theres a hardware lock feature included. Make sure you haven't accidentally switched the pin to "lock", which will only allow read-only access.